# Mongoose find() not working on foreign object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my schema.

```
const Sample = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  people: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'People' }
})

const People = new Schema({
  name: { type: String }
})
```

Now when I am trying to query the name of People schema using Sample schema.

```
var queryString = 'name of people'
const results = await Sample.find().populate('people').find({
  'people.name': { $regex: queryString, $options: 'i' },
})
```

It's working if I am just querying the name of Sample schema but when I'm trying to query the name of People schema on Sample model there are no results.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose populate supports applying query conditions:

```
const results = await Sample.find()
    .populate({path: 'people', name: {'APPLY YOUR QUERY CONDITIONS HERE'}});
```

Check the official documentation:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

Comment: It is not working, but based on the documentations I should be using denormalization and it links to MongoDB.

I tried match on populate doesn't filter the results but if makes other null if not in the  condition.